# Create workspace View URL in Docusign to display the workspace console for the user

Tags: c#, docusignapi

we are creating a workspace in DocuSign. so the user can acknowledge more than one envelope from the workspace console.

Docusign team has confirmed that we need to create a workspace and then include the workspace Id as the Custom field while creating the envelope. which we were able to implement.

once the multiple envelopes are created for the same user with the workspace Id,
what is the process to display the workspace console to the user?

Is there any method we can invoke to get the View URL of the Workspace console.

```
        const string username = "xxx";
        const string password = "xxx";
        const string integratorKey = "xxx";

        const string basePath = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi";

        // instantiate a new api client and set desired environment
        ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient(basePath);

        // set client in global config so we don't have to pass it to each API object.
        Configuration.Default.ApiClient = apiClient;

        // create JSON formatted auth header containing Username, Password, and Integrator Key
        const string authHeader = "{\"Username\":\"" + username + "\", \"Password\":\"" + password + "\", \"IntegratorKey\":\"" + integratorKey + "\"}";
        Configuration.Default.AddDefaultHeader("X-DocuSign-Authentication", authHeader);

        // the authentication api uses the apiClient (and X-DocuSign-Authentication header) that are set in Configuration object
        AuthenticationApi authApi = new AuthenticationApi();
        LoginInformation loginInfo = authApi.Login();

        Console.WriteLine("LoginInformation: {0}", loginInfo.ToJson());

        //Configuration.Default.AddDefaultHeader("Content-Disposition", "file; filename=fileName.ext");

        // parse the first account ID that is returned (user might belong to multiple accounts)
        var accountId = loginInfo.LoginAccounts[0].AccountId;


        // Update ApiClient with the new base url from login call
        string[] separatingStrings = { "/v2" };
        apiClient = new ApiClient(loginInfo.LoginAccounts[0].BaseUrl.Split(separatingStrings, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0]);



        // logic to create workspace
        WorkspacesApi workspaces = new WorkspacesApi(Configuration.Default);

        Workspace item = new Workspace();

        WorkspaceUser user = new WorkspaceUser
        {
            Email = "xxx",
            Type = "CompanyUser",
            UserName = "xxx",
            UserId = "xxx"

        };

        item.BillableAccountId = accountId;
        item.WorkspaceDescription = "Create workspce POC";
        item.BillableAccountId = accountId;
        item.Created = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        item.CreatedByInformation = user;
        item.LastModifiedByInformation = user;
        item.Status = null;
        item.WorkspaceName = "Create workspce POC";

        //uncomment below line to create workspace
        //var workspaceresult = workspaces.CreateWorkspace(accountId, item);

        //uncomment below line to list all existing workspaces
        var workspaceList = workspaces.ListWorkspaces(accountId);

        var workspaceId = "xxx";

        //uncomment below line to get details about the workspace
        //var worspaceresult = workspaces.GetWorkspace(accountId, result.WorkspaceId);

        EnvelopeDefinition envDef = new EnvelopeDefinition
        {
            EmailSubject = "[DocuSign C# SDK] - Please sign this doc",
            TemplateId = "xxx",
            Status = "sent"
        };



        // assign recipient to template role by setting name, email, and role name.  Note that the
        // template role name must match the placeholder role name saved in your account template.  
        TemplateRole tRole = new TemplateRole
        {
            Email = "xxx",
            Name = "xxx",
            RoleName = "xxx"

        };

        // add the roles list with the our single role to the envelope
        List<TemplateRole> rolesList = new List<TemplateRole> { tRole };
        envDef.TemplateRoles = rolesList;


        //custom fields to set workspace Id 
        var listCustomField = new List<ListCustomField>();

        List<string> listItem = new List<string> {workspaceId};

        ListCustomField listCustomitem = new ListCustomField
        { 
            Name = "workspaceId",
            Value = workspaceId,
            ListItems = listItem,
            Required = "false",
            Show = "false"
        };

        listCustomField.Add(listCustomitem);
        CustomFields customFields = new CustomFields(listCustomField);
        envDef.CustomFields = customFields;

        // use the EnvelopesApi to crate and send the signature request
        EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi();

        EnvelopeSummary envelopeSummary = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(accountId, envDef);


        //verify that the custom fields are set in the envolope
        var customFieldsummary = envelopesApi.ListCustomFields(accountId, envelopeSummary.EnvelopeId);

        Console.WriteLine("EnvelopeSummary:\n{0}", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(envelopeSummary));

        //below line will give the envolope details 
        var envolopeDetails = envelopesApi.GetEnvelope(accountId, envelopeSummary.EnvelopeId);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few problem is your code, you are adding remote signers in the envelope definition and trying to create recipientView for the remote signer, which is wrong. `RecipientView` is for Embedded Signers only, Remote Signer will do the signing ceremony from the email they receive in their Inbox.

`Workspace` can be used with remote signers only, so an email will go the remote signers and when they open the email they will be taken to the workspace where they can see all the envelopes which they need to sign.

Referring WorkspaceId in an envelope is done like below:

```
"customFields": {
        "textCustomFields": [{
            "name": "##workspaceId",
            "required": "false",
            "show": "false",
            "value": "63f6c74c-3f80-4ba5-bafb-d295c867f531"
        }]
    }
```

Comment: I was testing few options and i left that RecipientView code there itself. if we ignore that code, from the above code we are able to create workspace and create the envelopes. and we are passing workspaceId as the custom field. we are getting the mail in the remote signer mail box, but the mail is showing only one envelope rather than workspace.  is there any issue while creating the envelope with the workspace as the custom field input ?.

Comment: I have edited my response to make it work, you need to have `"name": "##workspaceId"` in your envelope custom field and value will be workspacId GUID.